# angular-cli is auto-injecting css files that I don't want?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

After installing ng2-smart-table library. I realised that angular-cli is auto-injecting css files that I don't want from this plugin since I need to define my own css.

how to have control over css injection in angular-cli ?

Comment: Did angular-cli add entries for the unwanted css in your angular-cli.json`file at the root of your project?

Comment: no it doesn't, but styles are applied when 'ng serve'

Comment: there is not way if the css is included on the module you are loading. you probably need to overwrite the css

Comment: the only solution I can have is to fork the repo and comment the css files which is not the cleanest way to solve this issue